# set -e in Bash scripts: discovering failure location?

Tags: linux, bash, error-handling

As we all know, we should use `set -e` to make Bash scripts [more robust](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html).  However, with this enabled, if the script *does* fail, is there any way to get Bash to report which line of the script failed?  At the moment, I'm having to re-run the script with a load of `echo` commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option I'm aware of for debugging with line numbers is to customise the "`+`" prefix printed by `set -x` to include `$LINENO`.

e.g. at the top of your script:

```
PS4='($LINENO)+ '
set -x
```

(Not exactly what you asked for, but it is handy!)

Answer (score 2):

You could just re-run with `bash -x` (or put `set -x` in your script to activate debugging, `set +x` to deactivate it later)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about line numbers, but if you combine -e (or -u) with -v you'll get the line where the error does occur as the last line printed in screen.

Comment: This also works less usefully with control structures - e.g. it will print an entire `while`...`done` loop before executing all of it, rather than showing it line-by-line as it progresses.